# nvs use command not working in git bash command prompt in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm

I have installed NVS using chocolatey in windows but when I use nvs use command it's not executing and showing command not found

[image: Command line error for your reference]

[image]

Not sure where exaclty wrong I am doing, I have followed steps (https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/blob/master/doc/SETUP.md) and created .bashrc and .bash_profile files in the same directory. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Can you add the o/p of `nvs --version` ? If it shows the installation, check `nvs ls` and add the o/p in the question code.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara Added it in description

Comment: As a node on windows user: what's nvs? The windows version of `nvm` is still a command called `nvm`, found over on https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows, which has a normal `.exe` installer, and doesn't require setting any env vars anywhere.

Comment: funny, because that's not the same repo as mentioned in the post, and they're not forks of each other, so... sounds incredibly sketchy?

Comment: I just did system restart and voila, it worked for me, this is strange

Comment: "What's nvs?" Answer: simply an alternative to `nvm` that claims to be faster.

My bad - not looking closely enough and I linked to a strange repo. Deleting my comment with bad link.

Answer (score 1):

The installer does add `nvs` to your `PATH`. If you have any console windows open you would need to close and reopen them for that change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: try using `nvs` from Powershell or cmd.exe instead of from Bash. The install from chocolatey creates `nvs.cmd` and `nvs.ps1` in the Windows `~/AppData/Local/nvs`.

Comment: This is helpful for me. Thanks. Win is really bad for developers, Linux and MacOS is better.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it uninstalling it and reinstalling from GIT Bash following this instructions (which installs nvs for the current user):

1- Run `export NVS_HOME="$HOME/.nvs"`

2- Then run `git clone https://github.com/jasongin/nvs "$NVS_HOME"`

3- Lastly run `"$NVS_HOME/nvs.sh" install`

4- Check if working, if not run: `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi`

Source: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs/blob/master/doc/SETUP.md#git-bash-on-windows

Hope it helps.